# Putting a variable name = value format in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to add some debugs for my simple ruby functions and I wrote a function as below,

```
def debug(&block)
  varname = block.call.to_s
  puts "#{varname} = #{eval(varname,block)}"
end

debug {:x} #prints x = 5
debug {:y} #prints y = 5
```

I understand that eval is evil. So I have two questions.

1. Is there any way to write that debug method without using eval? If NO is there a preferred way to do this?
2. Is there any way to pass a list of arguments to this method? I would ideally prefer debug {:x, :y. :anynumOfvariables}. I could not quite figure out how to factor that into the debug method (i.e, to take a list of arguments)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use arrays. You can use the `Array` method to ensure that you will always have an array, even if someone passes in only a single value:

```
def debug(&block)
  Array(block[]).each do |var| puts "#{var} = #{eval var.to_s, block}" end
end

x, y = 3, 5

debug {:x} # => "x = 3"
debug {[:x, :y]} # => "x = 3" "y = 5"
```

BTW: passing a block as the binding no longer works in Ruby 1.9. (Despite the fact that the documentation says it *does* work.) You have to explicitly call `Proc#binding` to get a `Binding` object for that `Proc`:

```
def debug(&block)
  Array(block.()).flatten.each do |var|
    puts "#{var} = #{eval var.to_s, block.binding}"
  end
end
```

Fortunately, this *already* works in Ruby 1.8, so you can futureproof your code by including it.

An alternative would be to forgo the block altogether. I mean, you *already* force the user of the `debug` to use the unfamiliar idiom of passing arguments in the block instead of in parentheses. Why not force them to just pass the binding instead?

```
def debug(*vars, bnd)
  vars.each do |var|
    puts "#{var} = #{eval var.to_s, bnd}"
  end
end

x, y = 3, 5

debug :x, binding # => "x = 3"
debug :x, :y, binding # => "x = 3" "y = 5"
```

This has the added flexibility that they can actually pass a *different* binding than the one at the callsite, e.g. if they want to actually debug a piece of code in a different piece of the application.

---

BTW: here's some fun with Ruby 1.9.2's parameter introspection (`Proc#parameters`):

```
def debug(&block)
  block.parameters.map(&:last).each do |var|
    puts "#{var} = #{eval var.to_s, block.binding}"
  end
end

x, y = 3, 5

debug {|x|} # => "x = 3"
debug {|x, y|} # => "x = 3" "y = 5"
```

Comment: @Jörg, nicely done.  Do you think that `Array(stuff)` would read better than `[*stuff].flatten?`

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: Probably. Frankly, I just didn't think of it, because the splat-flatten idiom is so deeply burnt into my brain. `Array()` breaks if you pass more than one argument, which is why I avoid it, but in this case the language specification guarantees that rest arguments will *always* be an array.

Comment: Very nice write-up, Jörg. This helped me understand some stuff about blocks that confused me for a long time. +1

Comment: Jörg, can you explain what `binding` does for the `def debug(*vars, bnd)` example?

Comment: @smotchkiss: ... where it was defined, therefore we need to get a hold of the `Binding` at that place. In *this* example, we pass the `Binding` into the method explicitly as an argument. In the other examples, we use a `Proc` object (or more precisely, we use a block which we convert into a `Proc` with the `&` sigil). In Ruby, blocks are closures (i.e. they "remember" the variables that existed at the place where they were defined, and not where they are executed), which means that they carry a `Binding` around with them. So, we can extract the `Binding` from the block instead of passing it.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, 17K reputation and you haven't asked even a single question. I've been reading your responses all afternoon and they're by far the best I've seen on stackoverflow. You are my hero <3

Comment: @smotchkiss: I *tried* to ask questions, but when I started to type them in, the autosuggestion feature popped up, and ... they were all *already* answered :-) That's the true power of StackOverflow: you get your questions answered *before* you even ask them. It's like what the Python community calls the "Guido Time Machine": for every piece of code you want to write, there's already a module in the standard library that solves your problem.

Comment: @Jörg, I'm still reading your answers! Even if they're unrelated to things I'm learning about or interested in! What path did you take to acquire all of this knowledge? I aspire to have mastery such as yours. Perhaps I can contact you personally? You can find my contact details in my profile :)

Answer (score 0):

And how I must use those methods to get names and values of variables from **each** loop, to place them as keys and values of nested hash?

The *attributes array is passed as an method's parameter.
I want to iterate through it, and every variable's name use as a key to nested hash and variable's value as value.

I got this:

```
def get_varname(&block)
    varname = block.call.to_s
    return varname
end

def create_instance_hash(env_attrs_obj, *attributes)
    if not env_attrs_obj.has_key?("instances")
        env_attrs_obj["instances"] = ""
    end
    attributes.each do |attr|
        attr_name = get_varname{:attr}
        env_attrs_obj["instances"][attr_name] = attr
    end
end

instance_nat_ip_pub = "ip_pub_addr"
instance_nat_ip_prv = "ip_addr"
instance_nat_ami = "AMI_NAME"
instance_nat_aws_ssh_key_id = "AWS_SSH_KEY_ID"
instance_nat_id = "instance_id"

env_hash = {}

create_instance_hash(env_hash, *[instance_nat_ip_pub, instance_nat_ip_prv, instance_nat_ami, instance_nat_aws_ssh_key_id, instance_nat_id])
```

But:

```
def attrs_each_test(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attr|
        puts get_varname{:attr}
    end
end
```

And it outputs:

```
attr
attr
attr
attr
attr
```

The error [when I run](http://codepad.org/R3pADPfG) this **create_instance_hash**:

```
Line 12:in `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)
    from t.rb:12:in `create_instance_hash'
    from t.rb:10:in `each'
    from t.rb:10:in `create_instance_hash'
    from t.rb:24
```

How I can correct this error and achieve my goal?